# Material2 cdk Scrollable never initialized

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I am trying to use the new APIs to listen to scroll events in Material2.
I imported the ScrollDispatchModule in my app.module.ts and annotated a container with cdkScrollable directive as in

```
<div cdkScrollable>
   <div class="my-content">
   ...
   </div>
   <footer class="my-footer">
   ...
   </footer>
</div>
```

I would like to access it in the component with ViewChild and subscribe to events like this but the scrollable variable is always undefined:

```
  @ViewChild(Scrollable) scrollable: Scrollable; 

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.scrollable.elementScrolled().subscribe(scrolled => {
         //do stuff
     });
  }
```

Am I using these APIs in the right way?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar's answer is correct if you're using the snapshot builds. If you are using beta.12, what you've written should work. Check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-yzyhjd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: for some reason now it works, don't ask me why...maybe there was some other apparently unrelated error I solved in the meantime. I still got an `undefined` returned by `scrollable.getElementRef()` I was using to get a reference of the div, but got it anyway using the Event target instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Scrollable` directive have been moved out to `@angular/cdk` module. Since then inspite of `Scrollable` class, you should be using for [**`CdkScrollable`**](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/scrolling/scrollable.ts#L23).

```
@ViewChild(CdkScrollable) scrollable: CdkScrollable;
```

Comment: The directive name is `Scrollable` so I don't believe this would work

Comment: @WillHowell I checked Angular Material API, [check here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/cdk/scrolling/scrollable.ts#L23)

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the docs site, and it's been updated since the last release. You'll get a +1 from me if you update your answer to clarify.

Comment: @WillHowell thanks, I edited answer. Feel free to add if you want to. I'll accept the edit :)

Comment: thanks, I am using beta.12 so the class name is still Scrollable.